# Is it possible to set a Swift UI View in a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In a `UICollectionViewCell`, is it possible to set a SwiftUI `View`?

```
struct MyView: View {
 // ...
}

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.contentView.addSubview(MyView())  // How to set this?
    }
}
```

For the collection view cell, I want to use a Swift UI view. How to set the `UICollectionViewCell`'s content view to `MyView`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56788693/10900045

Using `UIHostingController` we can add a SwiftUI view to a UIKit view.